# Python tkinter GUI loading differently between Python IDLE+Shell and Terminal

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, terminal, python-idle

I have a tkinter GUI that is set up to work in both Python 2.7 and 3. I programmed it using the standard "Python IDLE + Python 3.6.0 Shell". However, upon doing some test runs using Terminal (such as `python3 filename.py`) or within a conda python2 environment (via `python2 filename.py`), I've found that Terminal outputs a tkinter GUI that has some subtle flaws (please see attached images).

[image]

[image]

On the left is Python IDLE+Shell (how I'd like to see the GUI), on the right is Terminal.

1. The colors are much darker in the Terminal version
2. Menu: There is a white edge on the menu screen border (left side and partial top side) in the Terminal version
3. Page1: The page is being cut off at the bottom in the Terminal version (due to fixed dimensions per frame); each label appears to be taking up more space, and pushing the widgets below the frame cutoff. This is the same for all other pages (other pages not shown in this post)

Can anyone shed light on this problem?

**UPDATE 1:** Using Bryan's suggestion below, I went in and manually set my label text and heights for each widget; the combination of `text=` and `self.label1.config(height=1)` did the trick. As said, it appears the terminal takes certain values by default that differ from IDLE's; thus explicitly defining all values is the correct methodology.

Still not sure about the color shift (darker in Terminal) or the `place()` visual glitch on the splash screen.

**UPDATE 2:** After some experimenting, the menu image actually has a white border natively around the ext. edge, which is only being seen in the Terminal window. Setting up the frame like below fixes the problem:

```
    bg_image=Tk.PhotoImage(file=img_path1)
    bg_label=Tk.Label(self,image=bg_image,borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0)
    bg_label.bg_image = bg_image
    bg_label.place(anchor='nw')
```

Still don't know why the colors are getting darker in the Terminal version - so I'm leaving this as an **open question**.

Comment: It's probably due to some things that IDLE changes about the default configuration of tkinter. For example, it looks like it's using a different default font. The reason the GUI is cut off is probably because you're either using `place`, or you've turned geometry propagation off and are trying to use fixed sizes.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley! I've updated my post above to show the changes that are needed.  I'm still not sure about the menu page or color change - I'm using `bg_label.place(anchor='nw',x=-2,y=-2)` in the IDLE; is there an extra default I'm missing that might be being altered between the two instances?

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay, figured it out and updated my post above. I don't see a way to accept your comment as the right answer, so if you want to officially make a post, I'll do that.  Thanks again for your continued help!

Comment: @evambivalence You can create a community wiki post with the answer you've got if Bryan's comment was drastically helpful.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am somewhat dubious that IDLE has changed the default configuration of tkinter, especially in the user process that runs user code.  If it did, I would consider doing so to be a bug to be fixed.)  I don't see any font difference, so why do you think the default has been changed?  How could it be changed?

Comment: I added the MacOS tag because I suspect that this is an issue specific to Macs. If python2 and python3 used different versions of tcl/tk, I would not be surprised at minor variations.  Are the images from using the same python3 binary, and hence the same tcl/tk, for both?  Were both windows on the screen at the same time, side by side, so that the posted image is from a single capture?  (To me, the left images look wrong in lacking the red, yellow, and green in the circles, but I am not sure what is normal.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, I'm using a global `if sys.version_info[0] < 3:` `else:` format for importing Python2 and Python3 tk modules in the same script.  Both windows were on the same screen at the same time when the screenshot was taken; one from IDLE, one from Terminal.  Thank you for your feedback on aesthetics, perhaps I should up the contrast on the image I'm using to pull out those colors more.  Regardless, the image I preferred prior to your valued feedback was the one on the left (IDLE).

Comment: @Nae thank you, I didn't know that was an option.  Perhaps if more light is shed on the internal mechanics at work here, that would make for a very good option.

Comment: @evambivalence  I should have remembered and noted that what I see in Firefox's rendition of SO's display of the screen capture, on my monitor, is probably different from the live display on your monitor.  You eliminated one possible cause -- different capture times -- but did you use 3.6 in the monitor also?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I just retested the setup with a constant Python 3.6 in IDLE. I compared it to both a Python 2.7 environment and a Python 3.6 in Terminal via conda. There was no difference between the Terminal environments, and each still appear equally darker than the Python IDLE.

Comment: Another test: add to your tkinter-using .py file this statement: `import idlelib.macosx as mac; mac.setupApp(root, None)`, where `root` is whatever you call the main, Tk() window.  If this runs without raising an exception, I expect it to have no visible effect when running either from IDLE or terminal.

Comment: Placing the `import idlelib.macosx as mac` at the top of my code and the `mac.setupApp(app, None)` directly above `app.mainloop()`, I receive no errors when running from IDLE or Terminal. @TerryJanReedy

Comment: And I presume it did not change the output.  I am out of ideas at the moment.